# Is the concept "space" actually needed?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I started making my mind around space and time and recently came to a point where I wondered if the concept of "space" is actually needed to describe physical processes at all and not just some concept that could entirely drop out by the fact that the "speed" of light / information is constant in some "rest" frame?

My thoughts were since any distance can actually be described by some value c*t (where t means number of ticks in some "rest" frame and influenced by some strange concept called mass) couldn't physical systems be described just by using these values and never using any space coordinates?

Where, diving further down, speed of information would mean that some physical processes have to tick a certain time uninfluenced by another until they can interchange again which is usually interpreted as distance (otherwise they would be indistinguishable by some third or other processes).

Are there any known works or further pointers regarding this?

Comment: what about the three dimensions of space? they do make a large difference. Then if you have three vectors you are just talking about changing units .

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are suggesting changing the number of dimensions used to describe spacetime (this won't work), or just rewriting each of the space components as a rescaled time component (this will work, but it's really just a change of units.)  Perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: I think you have a good question, but unfortunately I don't have a good answer......I would say that the concept of space is obviously  useful on an everyday classical level, (as a distance indicator),   but it fails when dealing with very small  or very large distances. I personally think of space as a relationship between objects on these extreme scales, rather than as an  indicator of how much time it takes to get from my house to some particular location. You might read Lee Smolin or John Barrow for some semi philosophical discussions of what space "is".

Answer (score 1):

To identify points in spacetime you need four coordinates such as $(t,x,y,z)$. That is, the $t$ coordinate gives you the position in time and the three spatial coordinates $x,y,z$ give you the position in space.

There's nothing to stop you dividing the spatial coordinates by $c$, e.g. to get $t_x = x/c$, $t_y = y/c$ and $t_z = z/c$, and then using four *time* coordinates $(t, t_x, t_y, t_z)$, but it isn't clear what this achieves. All you are doing is measuring spatial positions in light seconds instead of metres. You still need four coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

> My thoughts were since any distance can actually be described by some
>   value c*t (where t means number of ticks in some "rest" frame and
>   influenced by some strange concept called mass) couldn't physical
>   systems be described just by using these values and never using any
>   space coordinates?

That *is* a space coordinate. distance (space) = velocity x time, or in your units, d = c * t.

But to take a step back for a second, you're reading about what we now call Special Relativity. This was "replaced" (well...) by General Relativity. Under GR, space and time are combined into a single "thing", spacetime.

Now what exactly does that mean? Well, it's basically the inverse of what you're thinking of... instead of describing the universe as a "space" and things moving about within it that you notice by measuring "time", it combines all such measurements into a single value. So instead of (x,y,z) in 3-space, you have (t,x,y,z) in 4-space.

This might sound like just words, but it has real effects. An object moving at (1,1,1,1) and another at (1000000,1,1,1), that is, differing "only in time", may have significantly different outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using (t, x/c, y/c, z/c) instead of (ct, x, y, z) in SR seems attractive. It acknowledges that time has a special role to play in SR:

- timelike histories in space-time are naturally parameterized using clocks
- space-time is *Lorentzian*, not *Euclidean*: space-time geodesics are curves of *greatest proper time*, not curves of *least length*

I don't know of any authors that actually use this convention, however.

On an esthetic level, I find it attractive because it pushes you forcefully away from thinking about Euclidean analogies.... It has a "*You're not in Kansas anymore*" kind of perspective.